Method does not override any method from its superclass In Flutter
When I am trying to run my Flutter application on iPhone 15, I am getting an error similar like this.

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 15 Pro in debug mode...
Xcode build done.
Failed to build iOS app
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Method does not override any method from its superclass /Users/Vishnu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_inappwebview_ios-1.1.0/ios/Classes/InAppWebView/InAppWebView.swift:1431:25
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro.
Exited (1).


Please provide your Pubspec.lock and Xcode version

I also just started getting this

@Sameri11, How can I give the Pubspec.lock? Because it is a big file right.
Xcode version is 15.4

I think this problem is fixed in latest version of flutter_inappwebview as per this issue. Just update to version 6.1.0+1 in your pubspec.yaml, like this:
  flutter_inappwebview: ^6.1.0+1

If, for some reason, update is impossible, one can update only iOS implementation, like this:
flutter_inappwebview_ios: 1.1.0+1

But I believe it's very rare situation, when you can't update patch version of dependency (flutter_inappwebview) so first way from this answer is preferred.

@Sameeri11 The issue got solved right now. Issue was with syncfusion_flutter_charts package. After upgrading this package the error got solved. Initially the error was related to cocoapods after that above error came. I cleared the all changes and upgraded syncfusion_flutter_charts package. Then the error got solved. Thanks for your response and support. Thanks a lot.

Did you upgrade with flutter upgrade? Anyway, I think that flutter_inappwebview_ios was the root cause, since it's clearly visible from error you provided. I bet that it implicitly updated when you upgraded syncfusion_flutter_charts. Anyway, glad your issue is resolved, happy coding!

I fixed by upgradeing flutter_inappwebview to latest version in pubspec.yaml file for this package which caused the problem.
Packages can you found in the folder /.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/
You need to know which package have old version of flutter_inappwebview which cause the problem.
flutter_inappwebview: ^latest_version

in my case html_editor_enhanced_android_fix had old version of flutter_inappwebview  in pubspec.yaml
